# jQuery Sum table td and allow only 100 total

Tags: jquery

I want to sum table columns of class total of all the table rows. and display the total at the last row also I want to allow only total=100 to submit the form otherwise an error message will be shown.

I found below code and I tried to change it but its not working:

Code

```
    $(document).on("input", "input:text", function () {
        var strClass = $(this).prop("class");
        var intTotal = 0;
        $.each($("input:text." + strClass), function () {
            var intInputValue = parseInt($(this).val());
            if (!isNaN(intInputValue))
            {
                intTotal = intTotal + intInputValue;
            }
        });
        $(this).parent("tr").siblings("td").text(intTotal);
    });
```

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Size 1</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="productA"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Size 2</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="productA"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Size 3</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="productA"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TOTAL</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Somayah/1njcq99v/10/)

***Please advise***

Comment: $(tdis) should be $(this)..!

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti Updated :")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the easiest way to do it:

```js
$(document).on("keyup change", "input.productA", function () {
    var total = 0;
    $("input.productA").each(function(){
        var value = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    if (!isNaN(value)){
             total = total + value
        } 
        if(total < 100){
             $("tr > td:contains('TOTAL')").next().html(total).removeClass("error")
        }
        else $("tr > td:contains('TOTAL')").next().html("Limit 100 reached").addClass("error")
    })
});
```

```css
.error{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Size 1</td>
    <td><input type="number" class="productA" min="0"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Size 2</td>
    <td><input type="number" class="productA" min="0"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Size 3</td>
    <td><input type="number" class="productA" min="0"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TOTAL</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @SliverSurfer Can I ask what change can be done to make the validation must be as following: rows = 100 not less not more but columns can be <=100 and not more than 100 ? please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
$(document).on("input", "input:text", function () {
    var strClass = $(this).prop("class");
    var intTotal = 0;
    $.each($("input:text." + strClass), function () {
        var intInputValue = parseInt($(this).val());
        if (!isNaN(intInputValue))
        {
            intTotal = intTotal + intInputValue;
        }
    });
    $(this).closest("tr").siblings("tr:last").find("td:last").text(intTotal);
});
```

You also have a type error: `$(tdis)` should be `$(this)`

```js
$(document).on("input", "input:text", function () {
    var strClass = $(this).prop("class");
    var intTotal = 0;
    $.each($("input:text." + strClass), function () {
        var intInputValue = parseInt($(this).val());
        if (!isNaN(intInputValue))
        {
            intTotal = intTotal + intInputValue;
        }
    });
    $(this).closest("tr").siblings("tr:last").find("td:last").text(intTotal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Size 1</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="productA"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Size 2</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="productA"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Size 3</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="productA"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TOTAL</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/1njcq99v/11/

- handle input event
- loop on each `total` class input textbox and sum the value

Code

```
$(".warning").hide();

$(".total").on("input", function () {

    var intTotal = 0;
    $(".total").each(function(index, el) {
        var intInputValue = parseInt( $(el).val() );
      if (!isNaN(intInputValue)) {
        intTotal = intTotal + intInputValue;
      }

    });

    // $.each($("input:text." + strClass), function () {
    //     var intInputValue = parseInt($(tdis).val());
    //     if (!isNaN(intInputValue))
    //     {
    //         intTotal = intTotal + intInputValue;
    //     }
    // });

    $(".my-sum").text(intTotal);
    if (intTotal > 100) {
        $(".warning").show();
    }

});
```

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Size 1</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="total"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Size 2</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="total"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Size 3</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="total"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TOTAL</td>
    <td><span class="my-sum"></span></td>
  </tr>

</table>
<div class="warning">Total must not be bigger than 100</div>
```

Comment: I added `my-sum` class to easily find the text total to update ;)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on("change", "input:text", function () {
        var strClass = $(this).prop("class");
        var intTotal = 0;
        $.each($("input:text." + strClass), function () {
            var intInputValue = parseInt($(this).val());
            if (!isNaN(intInputValue))
            {
                intTotal = intTotal + intInputValue;
            }
        });
        $('.sum').text(intTotal);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>Size 1</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="total"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Size 2</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="total"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Size 3</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="total"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TOTAL</td>
        <td class="sum"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`calculateSum` function calculate the sum and will also ensure that the button is enabled only if total is = 100.

```js
$(document).on("input", "input:text", function() {
  calculateSum();
});

function calculateSum() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.productA').each(function() {
    if (!isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())))
      total += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  $('table tr:last td:eq(1)').text(total);
  $(".submitButton").prop('disabled', false);
  if (total == 100) {
    $(".submitButton").prop('disabled', true);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Size 1</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="productA"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Size 2</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="productA"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Size 3</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="productA"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TOTAL</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button class='submitButton'>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on("input", "input:text", function() {
  calculateSum();
});

function calculateSum() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.productA').each(function() {
    if (!isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())))
      total += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  $('table tr:last td:eq(1)').text(total);
  $(".submitButton").prop('disabled', false);
  if (total != 100) {
    $(".submitButton").prop('disabled', true);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Size 1</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="productA"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Size 2</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="productA"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Size 3</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="productA"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TOTAL</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button class='submitButton'>Submit</button>
```